# Removing new lines except when new line preceded by double space

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove new lines from text, except when the sentence ends in a double space (I'm using JavaScript).

This:

```
This
is
a
test.
```

Should turn to this:

```
This is a test.
```

But this:

```
This
is  //there is a double space here
a//but not here
test.
```

Should turn to this:

```
This is
a test.
```

My approach so far: I can replace multiple spaces followed by a new line with a single new line:

```
var doubleSpaceNewline = new RegExp(/(\s){2,}\n/g);
test = text.replace(doubleSpaceNewline, '\n');
```

But then how do I remove the newlines, without removing the one I want to remain?

I would prefer to remove all new lines except newlines preceded by double or more spaces, THEN replace double space + newline with single new line.

I need a regex that will match `\s+` except when `(\s){2,}\n`. Can't seem to be able to combine both.

Comment: Does this count? http://jsfiddle.net/254b23jy/4 (edited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text = text.replace("  \n", '****************');

text = text.replace("\n", ' ');

text = text.replace('****************', "  \n");
```

Is this what you're after? Doesn't use regex, but its a bit simpler of a procedure.

Comment: This works, but I still used `/(\s){2,}\n/` in case more than two spaces are used, but followed the rest of your suggestion and it worked! Thanks.

Comment: Cool! Best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

To find "one new line if not preceeded but 2 *or more* (judging by{2,} in your code) spaces" with the help of regular expressions, you can use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html). Code for finding it is

```
(?<!\s{2,})\n
```

and then replace as usual.

Comment: It is my understanding that javascript does not support lookbehind. Sorry, just tagged JS, but didn't mention it.

Comment: Also sorry, I do not know JS, just wrote a general answer